# How to run PDFbookmarker in Python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to use this tool https://github.com/RussellLuo/pdfbookmarker but I am constantly given with error messages.

I installed portable WinPython, installed PyPDF2 via pip, downloaded add_bookmarks.py script and pasted it into WinPython catalogue, changed its execute rights, and just can't run it properly, why?

```
Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> add_bookmarks.py <test.pdf> [sample_bookmarks.txt] [FILE-new.pdf]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    add_bookmarks.py <test.pdf> [sample_bookmarks.txt] [FILE-new.pdf]
NameError: name 'add_bookmarks' is not defined
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I used another one: https://github.com/lstolcman/pdf_bookmarks and it worked.